# ACCOUNT_USAGE forced refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I know that many views under SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE will have a latency, some up to 3 hrs, so is there a way to "force" a refresh of the data, kind of like a ALTER ACCOUNT ... command or ALTER SHARE snowflake...?

I love the concept of checking metadata across all objects in the account but hate knowing some recent changes may not be present.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Snowflake does not provide a way to force the refresh of the views in the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema.

Here is a link to the [views in the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views) as well as their latency times.

In contrast, views/table functions in the Information Schema do not have any latency. They have much shorter retention periods though.
Link: [Information Schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html)

Comment: there is some mechanism that Snowflake is using to refresh the share SNOWFLAKE so it seems weird to me that it wouldn't be made available.  I'm not disagreeing with you, just disappointed I guess.

Comment: Understandable. It helps to remember that the SNOWFLAKE database in your account is actually an Inbound Share. So that data is being stors/maintained in Snowflake's account. Its just being shared to you. None of that makes it any less disappointing/ frustrating though.